# Retrieve comma-separated values from IQueryable and add to list

Tags: c#, linq, list, iqueryable

```
IQueryable<string> ScannedBarcodes = XYZDb.tblScannedBarcodes
                                          .Where(i => i.PullNo == lblPullNo.Text)
                                          .Select(i => i.Barcode);
```

The result view shows something like

```
"678765,090909,243454,675434"
```

Now I want to add all the comma-separated values into a list.

Rest of my code is below:

```
foreach (var item in ScannedBarcodes)
{
    List<string> _barcodes = new List<string>();
    _barcodes.Add(item);
}
```

How to split it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about a simple `.ToList()`then?

Answer (score 1):

The splitting can be done using Linq as follows.

```
var _barcodes =
    ScannedBarcodes.SelectMany(iString => iString.Split(new char[]{ ','}))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: It's not said that Barcode has property type string, but even if so, String.Split requires a character array, not a string, and String.Split does not work on an IQueryable, so you should do AsEnumerable() first

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
_barcodes.AddRange(item.Split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no a single string with commas - that's just the **debugger display**. The `IQueryable` is a enumerable list of values already.....

```
IQueryable<string> ScannedBarcodes = XYZDb.tblScannedBarcodes
                                          .Where(i => i.PullNo == lblPullNo.Text)
                                          .Select(i => i.Barcode);

List<string> _barcodes = new List<string>();
_barcodes.AddRange(ScannedBarcodes);
```

There's really no need to loop over those values - just create your `List<string>` and then add the whole `IQueryable` collection to it in a single call to `.AddRange()` ...

Comment: The database has a value like that **"678765,090909,243454,675434"**